# How can I shuffle two different lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

I want to shuffle two lists and combine them into one. But when I use `random.shuffle(a, b)` it throws me the traceback that the list object is not callable. How can I fix this problem and combine two lists? This is my code:

```
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
numbers = '1234567890'

a = random.sample(list(alphabet), 3)
print(a)

b = random.sample(list(numbers), 3)
print(b)

c = random.shuffle(a, b)
print(c)
```

Comment: is `a1` one of the expected output?

Comment: I think what you want is to replace `c = random.shuffle(a, b)` with `c = a + b` followed by `random.shuffle(c)`. random.shuffle modifies a list in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the second arguemnt to  [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is function which returns a value, not the second list to shuffle into the other:

> The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random().

Probably the simplest way to accomplish your goal is to simply combine the two lists and then shuffle the merged list:

```py
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
numbers = '1234567890'

a = random.sample(list(alphabet), 3)
b = random.sample(list(numbers), 3)

a.extend(b)
random.shuffle(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a with b, shuffle a, and then print a. You have to do this because random.shuffle modifies the list in place and it doesn't return a new list.

```
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
numbers = '1234567890'

a = random.sample(list(alphabet), 3)
print(a)

b = random.sample(list(numbers), 3)
print(b)
a.extend(b)
random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine *then* shuffle.

```
c = a + b
random.shuffle(c)
```

You're getting that error because [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is expecting its second argument to be a function:

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>
> Shuffle the sequence *x* in place.
>
> The optional argument *random* is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function [`random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random).